# Tkinter Buttons and threading

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, selenium, button, tkinter

i have a small gui with a group of buttons , said buttons when pressed call to several Functions , which take about 30 seconds to finish , so the Gui freezes , after searching a lot here for a fix , I found a way to do it and it seemed to work okay for the most part , when i run the script it does work , but after a few minutes running it just stops working

this is a simple function that takes 1 argument , that argument is another function's name.

```
 def prueba(fcn):
    thread.start_new_thread (fcn,())
```

here's the code for the buttons:

```
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=0,row=3)
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=0,row=4)
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=0,row=5)
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=1,row=3)
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=1,row=4)
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
    button.grid(column=1,row=5)
```

This is what the console shows when clicking on the buttons after a while.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "***", line 354, in <lambda>
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant Text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please provide a testable example. Something that can be copies and run as is to get the same error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That will help you to understand the problem, and until you fully understand the problem it will be hard for you to describe the problem to us.

Answer (score 0):

File "***", line 354, in 
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant Text",command= lambda: prueba(functionName))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

First, use partial instead of lambda as that should be easier to understand

```
from functools import partial

## create all buttons is of course the same as one button
button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Irrelevant text",
         command=partial(prueba, functionName))
button.grid(column=0,row=3)
```

Then use after() instead of Threading to schedule it (non-blocking) although we don't have much info on what you are doing so this is a solution that generally works.

```
def prueba(func_name):
    ## 100=one tenth of a second
    main.after(100, func_name, ())  ## () sends empty tuple to func_name???
```

Comment: I thought i cound't  use after() , because i want to call the function when I actually click the button. What i do is , open a webbrowser with selenium and test several things in a website, then the fuction calls driver.quit to close that browser , and only then , the gui starts working again , that freeze is what i meant to fix with threading .

Comment: Lambda is simple enough to understand. I don't think importing something else to solve the problem is the best option when you can use lambda instead.

Comment: _I thought i cound't use after() , because i want to call the function when I actually click the button_  You can set after for any wait time you want.  Using after(1. ...) waits 1/1000 of a second which is the same, practically speaking, as when the button is pressed.

Comment: _I don't think importing something else to solve the problem is the best option when you can use lambda instead_  The problem is that the OP is getting an error from the lambda statement, which is one of the reasons someone came up with partial.  If you don't want to import then you will be missing a lot of really good stuff in Python.  Also, note that lambda is also imported as part of the standard library.

Comment: But i don't want the function to be called automatically , I want to call the function when i Actually press the button , Don't see how using after is going to help me with that unless there's something i'm missing.

Comment: what additional code have you tried and tested?  I posted code that the button press calls-=preuba(), and it then calls the second function passed by partial using after().  Saying I do/don't think this will/won't work is pointless.  No point in continuing this thread as you have not tried anything.

Comment: I've adapted your example and it works , it calls the function but the gui is still freezing , preventing me from clicking any other button, which was the issue from the start and why i wanted to use threading so it doesn't hang.